# pgModeler can't see DB structure

Tags: postgresql, pgmodeler

I have 2 PostgreSQL DBs on my server. I've made all settings and can see both DBs in pgModeler, but it can't see non schemas non tables of one of these DBs.

[image]

I've already checked for permissions in DB settings, but they are totally the same for both DBs.

How can I solve this issue?